# Mocha - moch import outside of test environment

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Not sure if this is possible, I have a helper method that's used in 100+ files:

```
// helpers.ts
// exports a json object using export default
import STATIC_DATA from '@data/static-data';

export function getData(key: StaticDataKey) {
    return STATIC_DATA[key].include ? 'foo' : 'bar';
}
```

This helper method does a lot more than this, but i've simplified my example

In the test environment

```
import assert from 'assert';

it('should return foo when include is true', () => {
   const isFoo = getData('someKey');
   assert.equal(isFoo, 'foo');
});

it('should return bar when include is false', () => {
   const isBar = getData('someOtherKey');
   assert.equal(isBar, 'bar');
});
```

What i want to do, in each test is mock what the "STATIC_DATA" is which is imported in the helpers.ts file, so i can force the data to be what i want so the test remains true consistently, eg something like (which i know doesn't work)

```
it('should return bar when include is false', () => {
   proxyquire('@data/static-data', {
        someOtherKey:{
            include: false
        }

   });
   const isBar = getData('someOtherKey');
   assert.equal(isBar, 'bar');
});
```

I've tried using nock, sinon, proxyrequire but no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the test data to `STATIC_DATA` in each test case and clear it at the end of each test case.

`static-data.ts`:

```
export default {};
```

`helper.ts`

```
import STATIC_DATA from './static-data';

export function getData(key) {
  return STATIC_DATA[key].include ? 'foo' : 'bar';
}
```

`helper.test.ts`:

```
import { getData } from './helper';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import STATIC_DATA from './static-data';

describe('72312542', () => {
  it('should return bar when include is false', () => {
    STATIC_DATA['someOtherKey'] = { include: false };
    const isBar = getData('someOtherKey');
    sinon.assert.match(isBar, 'bar');
    delete STATIC_DATA['someOtherKey'];
  });

  it('should return foo when include is true', () => {
    STATIC_DATA['someKey'] = { include: true };
    const isFoo = getData('someKey');
    sinon.assert.match(isFoo, 'foo');
    delete STATIC_DATA['someKey'];
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  72312542
    ✓ should return bar when include is false
    ✓ should return foo when include is true


  2 passing (4ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 helper.ts      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 static-data.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: omg - that's so simple i feel stupid i didn't think of this